Is fullcalendar 5 compatible with angular 15+?
I'm in the process of updating my angular project from 13 to 17 and currently using fullcalendar/angular version 5.11.2.
Is this version compatible with Angular 15 to 17 ?
I managed to use version 5.11.2 of fullcalendar on my project on Angular 14 but not in version 15.
I could not find any information about that on fullcalendar website.

For Angular 15 and above, you should use Fullcalendar v6, see the v6 migration docs. The same page lists all the necessary information about the breaking changes.
Also in the v5 README it is stated that compatibility is from v9 - v14, thanks @MattD for pointing that out.

I did not downvote your question. Actually I agree that the documentation is missing a compatibility table.

Oh ok my apologize then.
I did manage to find the answer here: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-angular/blob/v5/README.md
@fullcalendar/angular version 5 supports Angular 9 - 14.
